# How do I get a question re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closing

About two weeks ago [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17435/help-me-to-find-a-western-rpg) was asked. It was closed for being too vague, even though the asker and several contributors had improved it.

I didn't see it until after it was closed, but I felt I knew the answer so I posted the only way I could - in a comment. I also flagged the post to draw attention to it, in the hope it would be re-opened. It hasn't been.

I think this question deserves a chance. How can I get it re-opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reopen a question, 5 people with 3k reputation must be convinced to click that 'reopen' button. The main problem is bringing attention to the question you want reopened, for closed questions are inherently less interesting than the others.

Reopening a question *is* much harder than closing one, that's true.

I suggest making your point on [**chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) during a busy time (EU evening/US afternoon), when a lot of people are online. You also can bump a question through improving (editing) it, thus bringing it to the top of the homepage again, but I take it that wasn't enough. Finally, you can bring it up on Meta like you just have.

In closing, I'd like to point out that a question closed by a moderator (or an employee) can *still* be reopened by the community. If a mod wants a closed question to stay that way, she should lock it.

(All of the above obviously applies to undeletion as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the community voting to re-open it, a moderator would have to perform that action.